Problemas con inner join
Tengo una base de datos con 2 tablas relacionadas. La primera llamada "bandas_solistas" tiene los campos id, nombre_Banda, genero, y desde.  Y la segunda tabla llamada "generos" tiene los campos id y genero.  Necesito que cuando listo las bandas, me coloque el género correcto ya que por algún motivo me está poniendo el género cuyo id corresponde a la tabla "bandas_solista" y no a la tabla "generos".
¿Donde me estoy equivocando?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.
Les paso los códigos.
La sentencia la hice así:
$sql="SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.id  ORDER BY nombre_banda";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 

El archivo php:
 <?php 
    include('conexion.php');

    extract($_POST);


    session_name('back');
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['is_logged'])) {
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 'PHPSESSID';
        $_SESSION['is_logged'] == 0;
    } 

    if  ($_SESSION['is_logged']==0) {
        header('location: login.php?mensaje=Se ha desconectado del sistema');
    }

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BANDAS Y SOLISTAS</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- ENCABEZADO / MENU -->
    <header>
        <?php
            include('header.php')
        ?>
    </header>
    

    <!-- BODY -->

    <?php 
   
       $sql="SELECT * FROM bandas_solistas INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.id  ORDER BY nombre_banda";
       $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    ?>

    <section>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Género</th>
                    <th>Desde</th>
                    <th>Modificar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                <?php while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <tr>                
                        <a><td><?php echo $registro['nombre_Banda']; ?></td></a>
                        <a><td><?php echo $registro['genero']; ?></td></a>
                        <a><td><?php echo $registro['desde']; ?></td></a>
                        <td><a href="modificar_bys.php?id=<?php echo $registro["id"] ?>"> <img src="img\icon_modificar.jpg" height="10" alt="Modificar"> </a> </td>
                        <td><a href="eliminar_bys.php?id=<?php echo $registro["id"] ?>"><img src="img\icon_eliminar.jpg" height="10" alt="Eliminar"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </section>
        
    <!-- PIE DE PÁGINA -->
    <footer>
    <?php
            include('footer.php')
        ?>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>


Pero si eso mismo estás poniendo en tu INNER JOIN... INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.id

Puede que el error esté en el INNER JOIN estas uniendo posibles PRIMARY KEYS de ambas tablas mas no los id que los relacionan entre si mismas.

Creo tener la solución de tu problema. Radica en la consulta SQL y como estas relacionando las dos tablas en el JOIN. EN la parte del ON tienes:
ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.id

Aquí estas intentando igualar 2 parámetros que no tienen nada que ver. Tienes que igualarlo con el elemento que corresponda como clave foranea de tu otra tabla. Por ejemplo el query que necesitas podria ser el siguiente:
$sql = "SELECT bandas_solistas.nombre_Banda, generos.genero, bandas_solistas.desde 
    FROM bandas_solistas 
    INNER JOIN generos ON generos.id = bandas_solistas.genero 
    ORDER BY bandas_solistas.nombre_Banda";

Contando que bandas_solistas.genero es el campo relacionado con la tabla generos.
Espero que te haya ayudado!
Un saludo.

Exactamente, ya le tocaría ver que columnas tienen relación entre genero y bandas_solistas,

Genial!!  Funcionó.  Sabía que el problema estaba con los id, pero no me data buenta.  Muchas gracias.

@MaxHD Recuerda aceptar una respuesta si es que esta te ha ayudado a resolver el problema
